# How to express synonyms in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have a rulebase which says that if our cake is bad than we should not eat it:

```
do_not_eat(cake) :- is_bad(cake).
```

Let's further say that that our brownie has gone bad:

```
is_bad(brownie).
```

How do I express in Prolog that brownie should be treated as a synonymous with cake and in consequence it should not be eaten? I know I could have rephrased the first rule with variables as

```
do_not_eat(Cake) :- is_bad(Cake)
```

and everything would unify nicely. However, I'd like to know if it's possible to say something along the lines of "make `brownie` synonymous to `cake`" or "anything that applies to `cake` should apply to `brownie`"? I tried adding a rule `cake :- brownie`, but it does not seem to do the trick. I have been using GnuProlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to change your rule to:

```
do_not_eat(Cake) :- cake(Cake), is_bad(Cake).
```

and define:

```
cake(brownie).
cake(cupcakes).
...
```

You can also generalize the solution. For example:

```
do_not_eat(Food) :- food(Food), is_bad(Food).
```

and then also define:

```
food(Food) :- cake(Food).
```

A more powerful but heavier solution is to define a hierarchy of objects representing your concepts. Then you can simply have e.g. brownie inheriting from cake and cake inheriting from food. Using Logtalk, which supports GNU Prolog:

```
------- cakes.lgt -------
:- object(food).

    :- public(do_not_eat/0).
    do_not_eat :-
        % ask the receiver of the do_not_eat/0 message if it's bad
        ::is_bad.

    :- public(is_bad/0).

:- end_object.


:- object(cake,
    extends(food)).

    % cakes are bad for your health
    is_bad.

:- end_object.


% anything that applies to cake also applies to brownie
:- object(brownie,
    extends(cake)).

:- end_object.
-------------------------
```

You can then:

```
$ gplgt
...
| ?- {cakes}.
...
% (0 warnings)

(5 ms) yes
| ?- cake::do_not_eat.

yes
| ?- brownie::do_not_eat.

yes
```

Comment: The `cake` rule is the standard way of doing this.

Comment: @IllidanS4 The best solution will depend on factors that are likely abstracted in the question. OP: "anything that applies to cake should apply to brownie". Also, are there only cakes and brownies or also pies, pizza, chicken salad? Is eating the only concern or also e.g. computing caloric content? That's way I mention two possible solutions. But there are more!